# A certain solution to the 1988 IMO question 6.

Tags: number-theory

I recently looked into the 1988 IMO 6, and found a direct proof that I took a liking to, found here: http://hkumath.hku.hk/~mks/MathematicsCompetitions_MKSiu_2012.pdf, on page 5, in the middle of the page.

However, I do not understand the part, right before that whole long line of math, the sentence that says that d' can not be positive.

If someone would care to explain this to me, as well as possibly share some other relatively easily understood direct proofs, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's a little ambiguous, I think "Proceed as before" implies we are still assuming:

> $a+b$ is minimal among pairs $(a,b)$ with $a,b>0$ and
>   $a^2+b^2=k(ab+1)$.

Since the pair $(d',c)$ also satisfies the equation and has $c>0$ and $d'+c<a+b$, it must fail the remaining condition $d'>0$.

Comment: I also do not quite understand why we have to have $c=min(a,b)$ and etc, why not just allow $b \leq a$?

Comment: @D.R. Setting $c=\min(a,b)$ and $d=\max(a,b)$ is similar to assuming $a\leq b$ wlog (I guess some people avoid wlog arguments because they require the reader to think carefully to confirm no generality was in fact lost).

Comment: And also, I don't get why the fact that $(d+1)(d'+1) \geq c^2+1 >0$ implies $d'+1>0$.

Comment: @D.R. Just divide by $(d+1)$ (which is positive since $d\geq a>0$).